# Avoid duplicate database access in get/post handling

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using asp.net MVC 3:

I have a view whose input fields are generated dynamically during the GET request (they are retrieved from the database). During the POST, if the validation fails, I have to redisplay the fields and therefore retrieve them again. Is there a way to avoid the redundant database access, i.e, is there a way to share some data between GET and POST requests?

Comment: Maybe straight asp.net with viewstate turned on is better suited for this.

Comment: MVC handles this fine.  Going to a broken asp.net model for the viewstate is going back to heating a house with a wood furnace because the fire can also cook your food.

Answer (score 1):

There is ways to handle this like storing the data in TempData or Session etc... But i think You should not do that way. You should always re query your data access layer and get it.  That does not mean you always query the db tables. Your Data Access layer can give you data from the cache or do a query against the tables.

Behind the Scenes, TempData Use Session to persist the values. The value of TempData persists until it is read or until the session times out. Persisting TempData in this way enables scenarios such as redirection, because the values in TempData are available beyond a single request.

Comment: Instead of using Session, what's your thought on using TempData? At least it would be limited to only that one round trip, instead of long term persistence like Session would be.

Comment: @Chris:Yes. TempData is another option.But behind the scene, TempData is using Session to persist values.

Comment: @Chris. I updated my answer to bring that point (how tempdata works). thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, but yes.

If when you post your form, you're sending all the data back to the server, and then sending that data on through to the model, your model will have all the data it needs to populate its fields.

There's posting via ajax to receive json data, and when you retrieve the results from the ajax 
 you populate only the fields that have changed.

However, I don't think that re-querying is that big of a deal unless you're talking about a particularly painful query of several seconds or more.

Oh, and don't store data in session or cache.  There's no reason to clog up ram with single posts, and this can open up potential issues later on if you mistakenly reuse session keys.

Comment: When I send the data, my model is populated only with the values of the input fields (but i need other things such as the label for each field, etc). The only way i found to correctly populate the models was to add a bunch of hidden fields with the data I need in the Post handling, but it looks pretty messy.

Comment: Well, I'm very concerned about scalability.

Comment: If you're adamant against requerying, which I am not sure is that bad an idea, even through scalability, then your only option is to send the data back to the server through a hidden field or ajax.  You can convert it all to json, and put the json into a single hidden field so when it posts back you can deserialize just one parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is 'lazy loading'.

Create a `static` variable (in the class that performs the database query) which will store the result of the database query when it happens, but initially it should be `null`.  Then create a getter method which checks to see if this `static` variable is `null` or not.  If it's `null`, run the DB query and store the result, otherwise just return the `static` var's contents.  Then always use that getter, and you're set.

I know particular pedantic people cringe at the use of `static` variables like this... but it works well, and with little fuss.